# which of the following languages over $\Sigma \{0,1,\$\}$ are regular?

Tags: computer-science, automata

i saw this nice exercise in some old summary and i was wondering if i got it correctly. basically i have to decide whether a language is regular or not and give a short explanation.
(languages over $\Sigma \{0,1,\$\}$)

1)$x_i,y_i,z_i \in \{0,1\}$ for every $1\leq n$, so that $x_1y_1z_1...x_ny_nz_n|x_n....x_1+y_n...y_1=z_n....z_1$

2){x$y$z | x + y = z} ($x,y,z \in \{0,1\}^+ $)

3)number of combinations of 01 in w = number of combinations 10 in w ($w \in \{0,1\}^*$)

my try:

1)not regular because n not seem to be bounded, and regular languages should have a finite boundary. however, maybe because of the addition i am missing something and it is actually bounded, but i think that it is not regular because the previous explanation.

2)since it is a finite set, we can use the pumping lemma to assert it is a bounded and thus a regular language.

3)not regular because number of combinations can be infinity, and because of the pumping lemma, a regular language should have a finite boundary.

for some reason when i try to use latex, it removes my {}, which are neccesary in logic and automata, and i don't know how to handle it to make it more readable.

tried to do my best and explain what i did and why and hope it's correct. if not, please correct me so i can learn from your answers and my mistakes and improve.

thank you very much!

Comment: In latex, you need to do this: `\{\cdot\}` to get $\{\cdot\}$.  The backslash must immediately precede each brace.

Comment: Why not apply the indication you received in the comment above, and correct the title and body of your question?

Comment: @did: fixed it, could you help with my question please?

Comment: "fixed it" No, you did not.

Comment: i've edited what i saw, if i missed something just tell me and i'll edit it. fixed few minutes ago the issue with the dollar sign that i missed in the previous edit

Answer (score 1):

A regular language is one that can be represented by a finite state automata, which is a very simple "machine" that doesn't have the ability to store any memory. That should give you a hint as to whether something is regular or not.

For instance, in the second language:

{xyz | x + y = z} (x,y,z∈ {0,1}+)

The value for "z" is dependent upon knowing the values of x and y, but these simple FSAs have no way of remembering that information. Keep in mind that the pumping lemma can be used to prove that this (and other languages) are NOT regular, but it cannot be used to prove that a language IS regular as you're asserting in your second point.

Comment: regarding what you've said, it seems that either 0 +1 = 1 or 1 + 0 = 1, but is that enough to assert it's finite? i really didn't understand your comment. were the other also incorrect?

Comment: A language being finite or infinite doesn't imply it is regular or irregular. Take the language A = { x* | x ∈ { 0,1 } }. The language A is the set of all values that satisfy the given rule. This includes: empty string, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111, 0000, 0001, 0010, ... , etc. The possibilities are infinite, and yet the language is regular and can be expressed by an FSA.

Comment: so if i understood what you said, could you tell me if now it's correct? 1)regular as the number of elements is equal(because of n), so it doesn't require special memory to "remember it". 2)you cannot remember the result and information, so it cannot be a regular language 3) also not a regular language as you can not remember the amount of 01 in w to compare with the amount of 10 in w.  is it correct now?

Comment: Honestly, I'm a bit confused about the notation used in the first language, so it's hard to give you an answer on this one. It seems like just an elongated version of language two where there are just multiple groups of these xyz patterns all next to each other. The subscript n doesn't actually mean anything other then just grouping them together, and so it can't be used as a means of storing anything as you seem to imply.

Comment: Your take on language 2 is correct, although that isn't a very exhaustive proof. You could use the pumping lemma to do this by assuming some pumping length P (it's not important what this number actually is), then make some string that satisfies the criteria of the language and is also longer than the pumping length P. This would necessity that some portion of your word can be "pumped" or just repeated however many times (or none at all). In order to prove that a language is not regular, you must show that there exists no substring that can be pumped like this and still be in the language.

Comment: As for language three, you've hit the nail on the head. @mathnoobie

Comment: thank you so much for your help! so regarding 1) as it's written, what would you say?

Comment: I would say it is irregular. Take the case where n=1: _x1y1z1 | x1 + y1 = z1_ This is the same thing as language two, which is also irregular. When n=2: _x1y1z1x2y2z2 | x1x2 + y1y2 = z1z2_ you would still need to store the _x_ values and the _y_ values in order to figure out what _z_ should be. Although it's confusing as to whether the _x1x2_ are supposed to be concatenated together (which is my guess) and then added to the concatenation of _y1y2_ to get the concatenation of z1z2 (e.g. _x1=0 x2=0 y1=1 y2=1 --> x1x2 + y1y2 = z1z2 --> 00 + 11 = 11 --> z1=1 z2=1_)